# After spending five months in the UK as a tourist and returning to Brazil for four weeks, can I then reenter UK on a short-term student visa?

Tags: visas, uk, brazilian-citizens

Since we are "non visa" eligible I would need to apply just when I get back to UK and I never heard about it before.

Is there anyone that did that before?

Comment: When you say "short student visa", do you mean you plan to get an actual visa, or to enter as a visitor without a visa and study during your stay? The latter is not allowed if studies are the main purpose of your visit.

Comment: Also, did you actually have a visa for your previous visit, or did you just enter as a visiting non-visa national? Note that the "leave to enter" stamp you get in your passport in the latter case is _not a visa_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think she means she wants to get admitted under  Paragraph A57A as a non-visa national.

Comment: @GayotFow: Makes sense -- I was not aware of that possibility.

Comment: I know people who have entered the UK that way for summer courses at accredited institutions; their entry was uneventful. What I don't know is whether attempting to enter for this purpose makes it any more likely that this second entry will go more smoothly than it would if you entered as a tourist again (I think this is what you are asking). Entering for a second long stay after a short period out is suspicious. Expect many questions about your actual intent and about what you were doing on your last visit.

Comment: I am from Brasil so I don`t need to apply for a visa. I came to UK as tourist which gives me an tourist stamp in my passport. And after spend 5 months and know more about the city, culture, etc, I found a very good university to make a marketing course which is my professional area.

Comment: So I would go back to Brasil after spend 5 months in the UK and get in to study this course since the start date for that is in May ( after my 6 months allowance). I have my bank statements proving I have money enough to stay without work, and also have a place to stay ( Brazilians friends since I was 6 years old that also have the rights to live here).

Comment: So do you guys think with all those documents - flight return tickets, bank statements,  letter from the school, letter from my friends about accommodation - is enough to get in again? Since I don`t need to apply before, I would need to take a risk to come and found out just in the UK at the immigration. I am afraid to just be sent back  to Brasil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a Brazilian national who has spent 5 months in the UK. You want to take a 4 week cooling-off period and then return and apply for a 6 month short-term student visa.  Brazilians do not need an entry clearance. You claim to be familiar with the visitor rules.

> So do you guys think with all those documents - flight return tickets,
>   bank statements, letter from the school, letter from my friends about
>   accommodation - is enough to get in again?

The answer to this question is **indeterminate**.  What you want to do is legal, and there are no required intervals or cooling-off periods between visits.  But on the other hand, the IO always has the option of refusing entry and having you removed. Moreover, the outcome of any interaction between a traveller and an Immigration Officer is wholly dependent on personal impact and articulation skills. You didn't give enough information about your personal impact to make a good guess (and we don't want all that information anyway). If you want you can hire an experienced practitioner (like a retired IO) to give you mock interviews.

BUT...  BUT... The 'golden' solution for someone in your situation is to apply for entry clearance before travelling. Even though you do not need one, having one means your landing interview is much simpler and much more like a formality. It happens this way because a British consulate will have already checked you out and concluded that you are 'cleared' for entry.

Our laws say that an entry clearance must be respected by an Immigration Officer at a port ([Paragraphs 25 and 25A](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk)). People who use them (but do not HAVE to have one) do so because it eases the transit of UK immigration controls and avoids wasted airfares and the distress of removal from port. Hence it's the 'golden' solution for anyone who is worried about what will happen in their landing interview.